# Convert image to monochrome and replace black with colour using Canvas and JS

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I'm trying to write some JS which will convert an image to grayscale, and convert the blacks to a colour (pink in this case). The effect I want to achieve is illustrated below (left is the original, right is the desired result):

[image]

I've tried using CamanJS and I've got something close-ish using a greyscale filter and a solid pink overlay with a blending mode of mulitply. The JS for this looks like:

```
$(function () {
    var $images = $('.make-pink');
    $images.each(function () {
        createPinkImage( $(this) );
    });
});


function createPinkImage ( $image ) {
    var $canvas = $('<canvas />');
    var canvas = $canvas[0];
    var imgSrc = $image.attr('src');
    var canvasWidth = $image.parent().width();
    var canvasHeight = $image.parent().height();

    var pink = '#d65fb3';

    $canvas
        .attr('width',canvasWidth)
        .attr('height',canvasHeight)
        .appendTo($('#canvas-container'));

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = imgSrc;

    image.onload = function() {

        Caman( canvas, imgSrc, function () {

            this.greyscale();

            this.newLayer(function () {
                this.fillColor(pink);
                this.setBlendingMode('multiply');
                this.opacity(70);
            });
            this.exposure(40)
            this.render();
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried to implement this in a jsfiddle but it doesn't produce a result. Here's the link anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/303L2xL4/1/

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

As you can see, it's not quite there!

Any help would be really great. I'm not committed to using CarmanJS is there's a better solution with another library or even just vanilla JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because black colors will produce black result as black is 0 and as you know anything multiplied with 0 will remain 0 (dark greys will produce close to black values and so forth).

To solve this you will have to add a brightness effect to the gray-scale image *before* setting its color (and potentially a slight contrast adjustment as well) to force the values up from 0.

You could also push the pixels through a RGB-HSL/HSV conversion, adjust brightness (L/V) and then convert back to RGB. This is in principle the same as a linear brightness but with typically better result/quality in the end.

Comment: Then multiply with the inverse :) .. Commenting because the fiddle does not seem to work for me; but, step 1: convert image to gray, 2. invert; 3. multiply with the inverse of 'pink': `#29a04c`; 4. invert again; 5. pink!

Comment: Thanks to you both. This seems to have worked well. And the invert technique adds a nice vibrancy.